# Open Social and Swiftmailer Emails Using IP Address instead of domain in some email notifications

Tags: emails

Drupal: 9.5.11

OpenSocial: 11.9.14

Swiftmailer: 8.x-2.3

Most of the email notifications in my set up work correctly. I'm having a hard time narrowing down which are problematic but it seems like at least any notification that is generated from a 'post' type has this problem. The problem being that in the entire email(so links and image src paths, etc) the domain is not used, instead the server ip address is used, breaking all links and image displays.

I'm looking for some guidance around how to track down the potential source of the problem. At first it seemed like it was only happening when I enabled a sub theme of the OpenSocial *Social Blue* theme, which may still be the case but not 100% on that. I need to be able to use a sub theme for customization so reverting to using the stock profile provided theme isn't really an option.